# _wrapped_view() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request' in django

Tags: python, django

I have a view just like this :

```py
@login_required(login_url='account:login')        
def editpost(request,user_id,post_id):
    if request.user.id == user_id:
        post = get_object_or_404(Posts,pk=post_id)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = editpost(request.POST,instance=post)
            if form.is_valid():
                slug = form.cleaned_data.get("body")
                slug2 = slug[:30]
                num_rand = random.randint(7486,20000)
                slug3 = slug2 + "-" + str(num_rand)
                ep = form.save(commit=False)
                ep.slug = slugify(slug3)
                ep.save()
                return redirect('account:dashboard',user_id)
        else:
            form = editpost(instance=post)
            return render(request,'editpost.html',{'form':form})    
    else:
        return redirect('Posts:index')
```

and form.py :

```py
class editpost(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Posts
        fields = ['body']
```

when i open editpost url i got this error:_wrapped_view() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
full track back:
AttributeError at /editpost/1/3
'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'user'

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:9999/editpost/1/3

Django Version: 3.0.6
Python Version: 3.8.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'posts.apps.PostsConfig',
 'account.apps.AccountConfig',
 'crispy_forms']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nima Aram\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Nima Aram\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Nima Aram\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nima Aram\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nima Aram\Desktop\wui\posts\views.py", line 61, in editpost
    form = editpost(request.POST,instance=post)
  File "C:\Users\Nima Aram\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 20, in _wrapped_view
    if test_func(request.user):

Exception Type: AttributeError at /editpost/1/3
Exception Value: 'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'user'
```

then , what should i do to fix it?(i added words here to fix stack over flow errors mostly code.)

Comment: please post the *full* traceback.

Comment: else: form = editpost(request.POST, instance=post) ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just forgot to deliver the required argument in your `else` function like so:

```
@login_required(login_url='account:login')        
def editpost(request,user_id,post_id):
    if request.user.id == user_id:
        post = get_object_or_404(Posts,pk=post_id)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = editpost(request.POST,instance=post)
            if form.is_valid():
                slug = form.cleaned_data.get("body")
                slug2 = slug[:30]
                num_rand = random.randint(7486,20000)
                slug3 = slug2 + "-" + str(num_rand)
                ep = form.save(commit=False)
                ep.slug = slugify(slug3)
                ep.save()
                return redirect('account:dashboard',user_id)
        else:
            editpost(request.POST, instance=post) # include `request`
            return render(request,'editpost.html',{'form':form})    
    else:
        return redirect('Posts:index')
```

Comment: but appears new error : AttributeError at /editpost/1/3
'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'user'

Comment: @KingOfPython please open a new thread if new errors arise, otherwise we end up with cascading tghreads which isn't helpful. however, your initial issue is solved